# What will be the cardinality of set if dimension of vector space is $1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a vector space over $\Bbb R $, where $\Bbb R$ is real numbers. Set $S$ is also given and its $ \operatorname{Span}(S)=V$. And I have to determine the cardinality of $S$.
And as per my understanding $\dim(V) = $ cardinality of $S$ ? But I am not sure whether it is correct or not?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $\dim V$ is not the cardinality of $S$.

Comment: $\dim V = \text{card }S$ if $\text{span}(S) = V$ **and** $S$ is linearly independent.

Comment: @GEdgar Can you please give an example, to help me understand this?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. The dimension of $V$ is no larger than the cardinality of a spanning set $S$, but might be smaller. Consider $S = \{1, 3\}$ when $V$ is the one dimensional space $\mathbb{R}$ itself. Without more information about $S$ you can't determine its cardinality.

In your first sentence you should say "where $\mathbb{R}$ is the real numbers, not "belongs to" the real numbers.

Comment: Thanks @Ethan, so cardinality can't be determined if vector space is finite dimensional?

Comment: No. A spanning set may have any cardinality larger than the dimension.

Comment: Can you please help me on this with an example?